# GROUP_CONCAT not returning all values if using WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have two tables; Packages and Users:

```
CREATE TABLE packages
(id int,  package_number varchar(20));

 CREATE TABLE users
 (id_package int, user_name varchar(20), 
 user_org varchar(20));


INSERT into packages 
(`id`, `package_number`) 
VALUES 
('1', 'PACKAGE-0001'), 
('2','PACKAGE-0002');

INSERT INTO users 
(`id_package`, `user_name`, `user_org`)   
VALUES
('1', 'John', 'ABC Pty Ltd'),
('1', 'Rebecca', 'Northshore Pty Ltd'),
('1', 'Grace', 'Northshore Pty Ltd'),
('1', 'James', 'Bank Pty Ltd'),
('2', 'Jonas', 'Northshore Pty Ltd'),
('2', 'Smith', 'Refi Pty Ltd');
```

I'm LEFT JOINing both tables based on id from Packages and using a WHERE clause to filter out the "Package Number" (which is a varchar).

I'm also combining with an AND clause to select which organisation it has been sent to, but at the same time I want it to return ALL organisations it has been to.

My code:

```
SELECT 
    packages.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (TRIM(users.user_org))
        SEPARATOR ',') AS recipients
FROM
    packages
        LEFT JOIN
    users ON packages.id = users.id_package
WHERE
    packages.package_number = 'PACKAGE-0001' AND user_org IN ("Northshore Pty Ltd")
```

output:

```
id  package_number  recipients
1   PACKAGE-0001    Northshore Pty Ltd
```

expected:

```
id  package_number  recipients
1   PACKAGE-0001    ABC Pty Ltd,Northshore Pty Ltd,Bank Pty Ltd
```

I've created a fiddle here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b58a1e/4

Comment: The `AND user_org IN ("Northshore Pty Ltd")` in your `WHERE` clause prevents it matching the other recipients. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b58a1e/6

Comment: I think you probably need a column which indicates whether the package is "from" or "to" a `user_org`

Comment: The current database design specs show that the Users table are all orgs it has been sent to. I've edited my post. 

Basically I'm trying to figure out how to filter by orgs, but i want to see which orgs the package has been sent to. I'm in the process of generating a report per organisation and this is a crucial step which I'm scratching my head over.

Comment: Typically, you would have a tables of packages, users, and organisations, and tables which relate those entities to one another.